# PHP Xpath how to get nodes after a certain node

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following HTML page

```
<body>
<a href="zzz"></a>
<h1></h1>
<a href="bla1"></a>
<a href="bla2"></a>
</body>
```

I want to loop thru the href elements after the `<h1` tag (so skip the tag with zzz url).
What xpath do I need?

Comment: Could you re frame the question ?

Comment: I think he wants to get `bla1` and `bla2`, because they are after an `h1` tag.

Answer (score 1):

This xpath should select the hyperlinks you want:

```
//h1/following-sibling::a
```